# Django. Thread safe update or create.

Tags: python, django

We know, that update - is thread safe operation. 
It means, that when you do:

```
  SomeModel.objects.filter(id=1).update(some_field=100)
```

Instead of:

```
sm = SomeModel.objects.get(id=1)
sm.some_field=100
sm.save()
```

Your application is relativly thread safe and operation `SomeModel.objects.filter(id=1).update(some_field=100)` will not rewrite data in other model fields.

My question is.. If there any way to do

```
  SomeModel.objects.filter(id=1).update(some_field=100)
```

but with creation of object if it does not exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

def update_or_create(model, filter_kwargs, update_kwargs)
    if not model.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs).update(**update_kwargs):
        kwargs = filter_kwargs.copy()
        kwargs.update(update_kwargs)
        try:
            model.objects.create(**kwargs)
        except IntegrityError:
            if not model.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs).update(**update_kwargs):
                raise  # re-raise IntegrityError
```

I think, code provided in the question is not very demonstrative: who want to set id for model?
Lets assume we need this, and we have simultaneous operations:

```
def thread1():
    update_or_create(SomeModel, {'some_unique_field':1}, {'some_field': 1})

def thread2():
    update_or_create(SomeModel, {'some_unique_field':1}, {'some_field': 2})
```

With `update_or_create` function, depends on which thread comes first, object will be created and updated with no exception. This will be thread-safe, but obviously has little use: depends on race condition value of `SomeModek.objects.get(some__unique_field=1).some_field` could be 1 or 2.

Django provides F objects, so we can upgrade our code:

```
from django.db.models import F

def thread1():
    update_or_create(SomeModel, 
                     {'some_unique_field':1}, 
                     {'some_field': F('some_field') + 1})

def thread2():
    update_or_create(SomeModel, 
                     {'some_unique_field':1},
                     {'some_field': F('some_field') + 2})
```

Comment: If another process creates the object between the two lines, the create() call will raise an IntegrityError.  You also are not setting the id in the create() call.

Comment: Ok, you right, it should care about IntegrityError. Will edit code.

Comment: Keep in mind that what you have posted above is already in the dev version of django's querysets:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Comment: At the moment - that is solution for problem.

Comment: In django 1.7+ you can use `update_or_create` method of QuerySet. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create

Answer (score 4):

You want django's [select_for_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) method (and a backend that supports row-level locking, such as PostgreSQL) in combination with manual transaction management.

```
try:
    with transaction.commit_on_success():
        SomeModel.objects.create(pk=1, some_field=100)
except IntegrityError: #unique id already exists, so update instead
    with transaction.commit_on_success():
        object = SomeModel.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=1)
        object.some_field=100
        object.save()
```

Note that if some other process deletes the object between the two queries, you'll get a SomeModel.DoesNotExist exception.

Django 1.7 and above also has atomic operation support and a built-in [update_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's built-in get_or_create, but that operates on the model itself, rather than a queryset.

You can use that like this:

```
me = SomeModel.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
me.some_field = 100
me.save()
```

If you have multiple threads, your app will need to determine which instance of the model is correct. Usually what I do is refresh the model from the database, make changes, and then save it, so you don't have a long time in a disconnected state.

Comment: Yes, and I do, but that's not thread safe. It will generate query like `UPDATE m SET field_1 = old_value1, field_2 = old_value2, some_field=100` instead of `UPDATE m SET some_field=100`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. There is no thread safe way to do this. You should be getting the latest from the database before you save it if you're using multiple threads.

Comment: By the way, the code that I posted above would be "thread safe" because as long as you do the get_or_create every time before you want to make an update, it will refresh from the database.

Comment: It matters, when I update 2 different fields at one time for one object on 2 different application servers(for example I update object from admin, and user updates his object from front-end). When we have first kind of query - object that is saved last will overwrite previous update with old values.

Comment: That's not a problem that is specific to Django, but even still, unless you hold the model in a disconnected state for a long time, you won't see that error AS LONG AS you always do the get or get_or_create immediately before you make actual edits.

Comment: I know, but my question is about thread safe method. I want something like `SomeModel.objects.filter(id=1).update_or_create(some_field=100)`...

Comment: That isn't thread-safe either though. If your database row is being updated at the same time that someone else runs a filter().update() like above, your row is going to lose that race condition. The only difference is that the update only updates a single column. For your original question, you would need to individually call get_or_create for each item. What you are saying is not a concept that ORMs can handle.

Comment: `get_or_create` returns tuple `(object, created)`

Comment: I know, that this is not conception of ORM. But by the way, I want to update single column in a row, not all columns :)

Comment: OK, well it's not possible without looping and with get_or_create. Again, as long as you don't hold the model in a disconnected state for very long anywhere in your app, this isn't a problem.

Comment: @NikolayFominyh I understand what you mean for update. The save method of Django model updates all fields instead of those modified in its thread, right? But what do you mean for create? If a later thread gets created=False from `get_or_create`, it should use column-updating instead of save(). Can you provide some scenes about it, thanks.

Comment: @okm, well it looks, like it is good idea to do get_or_create, and after it, if created=False - do filter().update()..

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in django do such upsert operation, with update. But queryset update method return number of filtered fields so you can do:

```
from django.db import router, connections, transaction

class MySuperManager(models.Manager):
     def _lock_table(self, lock='ACCESS EXCLUSIVE'):
         cursor = connections[router.db_for_write(self.model)]
         cursor.execute(
            'LOCK TABLE %s IN %s MODE' % (self.model._meta.db_table, lock)
        )

     def create_or_update(self, id, **update_fields): 
         with transaction.commit_on_success():            
             self.lock_table()
             if not self.get_query_set().filter(id=id).update(**update_fields):
                self.model(id=id, **update_fields).save()
```

this example if for postgres, you can use it without sql code, but update or insert operation will not be atomic. If you create a lock on table you will be sure that two objects will be not created in two other threads.

Comment: It will still generate query like `INSERT INTO <all_model_fields> VALUES <all_model_fields>`. It means, that if we will update in one thread `A.one_field` and in second thread we will update `A.second_field` - we will get trouble. Last updater will erase all updated fields with old data. **Table lock - anti-solution here.** It will raise exceptions periodically, but will not solve root of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have critical demands on atom operations. You'd better design it in database level instead of Django ORM level.

Django ORM system is focusing on convenience instead of performance and safety. You have to optimize the automatic generated SQL sometimes.

"Transaction" in most productive databases provide database lock and rollback well.

In mashup(hybrid) systems, or say your system added some 3rd part components, like logging, statistics. Application in different framework or even language may access database at the same time, adding thread safe in Django is not enough in this case.

Comment: And again. I just don't want django to update all fields on model save. All database level solutions will not work here. Because django itself takes **old values** from model instance, and updates model with them, even if we **changed only one field** in code.

Comment: If you don't care the final result, I mean the field value. You can use a task queue system(such as celery), set up one dedicated worker to update_or_create the record, all operations to the database will execute by sequence.

Comment: Celery is overkill here. :) `update_or_create` in django dev branch already, so question is not actual.

Answer (score -3):

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(id=1).update(set__some_field=100)
```

Comment: Please explain your code! Your answer is current being voted to close.