# Best way to create or update a through related set in Django?

Tags: python, django, m2m

I'm relatively new to Django and having some trouble with a through table relationship. I've looked at the documentation and can't find a good way to update a set without a ton of DB calls.

```
class Business(models.Model):
    customers = models.ManyToManyField('Customer', through='BusinessRelationship')

class Customer(models.Model):
    vendors = self.business_set.all()

class BusinessRelationship(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey('Company', blank=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', blank=False)
    value = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Let's say I have a figdety customer in my database who switches vendors a lot. I get a current list of his vendors and I want to update the business_set without iteratively asking the DB to update or save each item. Right now I have something resembling:

```
current_relationships = [\list of BusinessRelationship objects, some of which are saved, some are new\]
```

and I would like to save this for a customer all at once. Ideally I could figure out a way to do something like bulk_save_or_create below, which would avoid unnecessary database calls:

```
current_vendors = [\list of unique vendor IDs, ints not objects\]
my_customer.bulk_save_or_create(Business, current_vendors)
```

I know it's a broader question than usual, and that the 'best' aspect may be somewhat subjective, but there certainly has to be a standardish/accepted-djangoey way to do something like this and I my google-foo and docs reading has yet to identify it.

Edit: Anup, thanks for the suggestion. Was actually just looking at the Queryset#update_or_create method and realized that I essentially want a bulk version of that function.

Comment: I am not sure if i completely understand , but this should help you get some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990138/django-thread-safe-update-or-create

Comment: Possibly a bulk_create that ignored IntegrityError could work. It would reduce the process of updating the relationship to one select, delete and create call regardless of how many relationships are being managed.